# prevent some users from create conference by ucma

Tags: lync, ucma

I read many article about **UCMA** both USER Endpoint And Application Endpoint but a Very Important question for me is that How Can I Prevent some users from Create conference?

Answer (score 0):

Look to Set-CSConferencingPolicy documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425788.aspx)